# Unable to hear from speaker in android

Tags: android, audio-streaming

I am making simple wifi chatting application. The app has two methods for getting input from mic and playing to the speaker. The log of the app says that I am receiving voice correctly, but I am unable to hear any thing from the speaker. Please help me with it.

```
private void makeCall(final String IP_Address) {

//        New thread to make calls to the other phone

        Thread makeCallThread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.run();
//                start sending calls to the other phone
                int minBufSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat);
                DatagramSocket socket = null;
                try {
                    socket = new DatagramSocket();
                } catch (SocketException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.d("VS", "Socket Created");

                byte[] buffer = new byte[minBufSize];

                Log.d("VS", "Buffer created of size " + minBufSize);
                DatagramPacket packet;

                InetAddress destination = null;
                try {
                    destination = InetAddress.getByName(IP_Address);
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.d("VS", "Address retrieved");


                recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat, minBufSize);
                Log.d("VS", "Recorder initialized");

                recorder.startRecording();


                while (status) {


                    //reading data from MIC into buffer

                    minBufSize = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                    Log.d("VS", "I have read from the mic.");

                    //putting buffer in the packet
                    packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, destination, port);

                    try {
                        socket.send(packet);
                        Log.d("VS", "packet has been send.");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            }

        };
        makeCallThread.start();
    }
```

This method receives the call:

```
    public void startReceiving(View view) {

        Thread receiveThread = new Thread (new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {

                    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(50005);
                    Log.d("VR", "Socket Created");


                    byte[] buffer = new byte[256];


                    //minimum buffer size. need to be careful. might cause problems. try setting manually if any problems faced
                    int minBufSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat);

                    speaker = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,sampleRate,channelConfig,audioFormat,minBufSize,AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

                    speaker.play();

                    while( status ) {
                        try {


                            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);
                            socket.receive(packet);
                            Log.d("VR", "Packet Received");

                            //reading content from packet
                            buffer=packet.getData();
                            Log.d("VR", "Packet data read into buffer");

                            //sending data to the Audiotrack obj i.e. speaker
                            speaker.write(buffer, 0, minBufSize);
                            Log.d("VR", "Writing buffer content to speaker");

                        } catch(IOException e) {
                            Log.e("VR","IOException");
                        }
                    }


                } catch (SocketException e) {
                    Log.e("VR", "SocketException");
                }

            }

        });
        receiveThread.start();
    }
```

The log says the following:

```
08-24 23:21:52.639  20103-20450/com.example.shahjahan.udp D/VR﹕ Packet data read into buffer
08-24 23:21:52.639  20103-20450/com.example.shahjahan.udp D/VR﹕ Writing buffer content to speaker
08-24 23:21:52.689  20103-20450/com.example.shahjahan.udp D/VR﹕ Packet Received
08-24 23:21:52.689  20103-20450/com.example.shahjahan.udp D/VR﹕ Packet data read into buffer
08-24 23:21:52.689  20103-20450/com.example.shahjahan.udp D/VR﹕ Writing buffer content to speaker
08-24 23:21:52.739  20103-20450/com.example.shahjahan.udp D/VR﹕ Packet Received
08-24 23:21:52.739  20103-20450/com.example.shahjahan.udp D/VR﹕ Packet data read into buffer
08-24 23:21:52.739  20103-20450/com.example.shahjahan.udp D/VR﹕ Writing buffer content to speaker
```

But, speaker doesn't play anything. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: What's your `audioFormat`?

Comment: private int audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

Comment: According to the AudioRecord's [`read()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html#read%28byte[],%20int,%20int%29) docs you should use [`ENCODING_PCM_8BIT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioFormat.html#ENCODING_PCM_8BIT).

Comment: I am getting error Invalid audio buffer size.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid audio buffer size.
            at android.media.AudioTrack.audioBuffSizeCheck(AudioTrack.java:443)
            at android.media.AudioTrack.<init>(AudioTrack.java:316)
            at android.media.AudioTrack.<init>(AudioTrack.java:267)
            at com.example.shahjahan.udp.MainActivity$3.run(MainActivity.java:275)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

Comment: Did you change the audioFormat in the receiver part as well in all the locations? (minBufSize getter, AudioTrack constructor etc.)

Comment: yes, audioFormat is a global variable, used every where...

Comment: Okay, I see an error in your code: you use `AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(...)` in your receiver to get the minimum buffer size instead of `AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(...)`.